# Router to Firewall to Internal network NAT with Single Public IP

Tags: networking, routing, nat

In an effort to learn more about networking I have picked up some old Cisco equipment for home use. I have a 2811 router, a PIX 515e firewall, and a switch (don't remember the model).  My incoming connection is a DSL line with a single static IP address.

Here's what I want the network to look like when I'm done:

```
[Internet -> 2811 -> PIX -> switch]
```

My question is, do I need to use different subnets for the router-to-PIX connection and the PIX-to-switch connection?  For example:

```
Router external: <public static IP>
Router internal: 10.0.0.1

PIX external: 10.0.0.2
PIX internal: 192.168.0.1
```

Or can I put everything on the same subnet?

```
Router external: <public static IP>
Router internal: 10.0.0.1

PIX external: 10.0.0.2
PIX internal: 10.0.0.3
```

I believe if I use different subnets then I have to use NAT on the router and also on the PIX since I only have one public IP address to work with, correct?  The PIX can't route from its internal to external network if they are on different subnets.  I have seen a few references to this as "double NAT" which is apparently bad.

But if I put everything on the same subnet what do I set my default gateway to be for all the inside clients?  I think it would have to be the router's internal IP. But I don't know if the switch will be able to find the router on the other side of the firewall.

So what would you do in this situation?
Hopefully this is an easy one for you guys. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**The quick answer:** A typical home connection has only one IP address, and you will have to connect the PIX directly to the DSL and assign this single IP address to its WAN interface and leave the router on a shelf somewhere.  This is the only scenario supported by a typical ISP for a standard DSL home connection.

```
Internet -> PIX -> switch

PIX external: <public static IP>
PIX internal: 192.168.0.1
```

**The little more explanatory answer:** For you to be able to use the router between the ISP and your PIX, the subnet you use between the router and the PIX would have to be assigned to you and routed **by the ISP**.  You cannot pick your own subnet and put it there, since the traffic from the inside network appears to come from the PIX external interface, and that address has to be known in the routing system on the Internet in order to find its way back to you.

Let's for a moment say your ISP agrees to assign a subnet to you, the scenario you want to use will work, moreover, if the subnet is large enough to cover all device on the inside, you could change the PIX from routed mode to transparent mode. Then it would be possible to use the same subnet on both sides of the PIX.

A far better option for you to play with, is to have the router inside the PIX, and set up multiple subnets there, and do all kinds of fancy routing protocols and VLAN scenarios between the PIX and the router (and the switch if you have one that supports VLANs). That I would highly recommend you do for practice, since it will allow you to to much more stuff...

I hope this is helpful... :)

Comment: This isn't correct.  The 2811 can do the NAT and the PIX can use private addressing on both the internal and external addresses.  Besides attaching a PIX directly to DSL isn't a likely scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need different subnets for the internal and external networks on the PIX.  However, the network between the PIX and 2811 can be small, it only needs two addressable IPs, so you can use a /30 10.0.0.0/30 (although in your scenario you many not be concerned about conserving addresses so a /24 would be fine).

Double NAT is not applicable in this case as it refers to natting both the source and destination IPs of a packet, and generally happens at the near and remote end of a connection.

You are simply natting twice, which is fine.  On later releases of PIX software you can turn off the requirement to NAT between interfaces by setting them to the same security level and/or disabling nat-control.

Comment: I just learned about Transparent Firewall mode.  Would putting the PIX into transparent mode be better here to remove the need for two different subnets behind the router?

Comment: What version of PIX software is installed and what hardware?  Yes, transparent mode means one less subnet - but having a second subnet between router and firewall is very common. It is a design choice.   You can't have a DMZ when using transparent.  Also the 2811 with the right image can act as a perfectly good firewall too.

Comment: It's a PIX 515e running 8.0(4)